# What to check if db2 query returning 0 records

Tags: python, db2

I'm executing a db2 query from python 3.x.Before executing the query I'm extracting the python string for query & checking it in squirrel. The query is executing & returning results. Here is my query

```
select distinct Cno  from df_J_CUST where ID in ('95427','95405','95429') and  GRP not in ('K915B','K9F0S','K9M4U','K9QBJ','K0012AS','K0015R5','K001877','K001H1N','K95U5','K9GEX','K9M6L','K9YGP','K00159S','K00184E','K226QMF') and  CODE in ('1PY2','5AR1','9U1Y') and TYPE = 'L'
```

But while executing it from python using this code

```
    import pandasql as pdsql
    str1 = """select distinct Cno  from df_J_CUST where %s"""
    str="ID in ('95427','95405','95429') and GRP not in ('K915B','K9F0S','K9M4U','K9QBJ','K0012AS','K0015R5','K00187‌​7','K001H1N','K95U5'‌​,'K9GEX','K9M6L','K9‌​YGP','K00159S','K001‌​84E','K226QMF') and CODE in ('1PY2','5AR1','9U1Y') and TYPE = 'L'"
    str2 = str1%(str)
    print("str2=", str2)
    pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
    df1 = pysql(str2)
```

I'm not seeing any error message but the query is returning 0 records. Can you suggest me what I need to check to find out the issue?

Comment: ohhh man, why are you using `lambda` here and why `globals`? It is a big NO NO... why not just `pdsql.sqldf(str2)`?

Comment: also in your statement `str2=str1%(str)`, what is `str` holding? It is inbuilt type in Python

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri str="ID in ('95427','95405','95429') and  GRP not in ('K915B','K9F0S','K9M4U','K9QBJ','K0012AS','K0015R5','K001877','K001H1N','K95U5','K9GEX','K9M6L','K9YGP','K00159S','K00184E','K226QMF') and  CODE in ('1PY2','5AR1','9U1Y') and TYPE = 'L'"

Comment: The code in your question is incapable of producing that SQL without an unpublished assignment to `str` (thereby masking the built-in `str`). Please ensure all essential code is included in your question. You can edit it by clicking the "edit" link beneath it.

Comment: Hi holdenweb,only str used in my code was not there in my original post which I have added now. Kindly suggest me, according to  you, what should be the corrected code

Comment: Kindly note that this is my complete code. I don't have anything else. If you can suggest me solution then that will be very much helpful for me-Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion from anyone here?

Comment: Um, it looks like you're hitting two different table names?  `J_CUST` vs `df_J_CUST` - is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry @Clockwork-Muse ,it's typo.Corrected that